# Where to start on uploading a file to Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have a runnable jar file running Swing, and I would like to backup what has been saved to google drive. I have found the Google Drive SDK however it apperas that its just for ios android or html. Where would I start in trying to acheiver this?

The file is data.backup
I would like to upload it straight to Google Drive just in the default space i.e. no folders. This file is in the local drive and is in the same folder aas the jar file is located

Comment: Not enough details on what you are wanting to do. "I would like to backup what was saved" (to where - flash drive?, how - file copy?, from where - local drive? google?)

Comment: You could do a simple file copy to the local Google drive folder and it will be auto uploaded.